# Creating array from html to display using D3 Wordcloud

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, moodle, word-cloud

I'm afraid this is a very basic Javascript question on building an array from HTML elements. I've had a search for answers, but I think there's important fundamentals that aren't clicking for me and I'm going in circles, so some outside, expert perspective would be appreciated!

We're using Moodle to run an online course, and in the introduction week, we want to collect some information on users with a database module, such as country, and then show them the group responses.

Moodle give a template with a placeholder [[data]], which you can wrap in html, in this case a div:

```
 <div class="country">[[country]]</div>
```

The issue I'm having is getting the content of all these divs into an array. I found this method explained here, but my attempts to push/concat didn't seem to work:

```
var countryList = document.getElementsByClassName("country");    
Array.prototype.forEach.call(countryList, function() {});
```

The reason I want it in an array is so I can push the content into an existing template using Jason Davies's d3.js powered word cloud. [Here's a link to GitHub](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud), and the very basic code for a simple cloud is copied below for reference.

Essentially I want to be able to make an array from HTML elements and combine it with the words array used below:

```
var fill = d3.scale.category20();

d3.layout.cloud().size([300, 300])
  .words([
    "Hello", "world", "normally", "you", "want", "more", "words",
    "than", "this"
  ].map(function(d) {
    return {
      text: d,
      size: 10 + Math.random() * 90
    };
  }))
  .padding(5)
  .rotate(function() {
    return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90;
  })
  .font("Impact")
  .fontSize(function(d) {
    return d.size;
  })
  .on("end", draw)
  .start();

function draw(words) {
  d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(words)
    .enter().append("text")
    .style("font-size", function(d) {
      return d.size + "px";
    })
    .style("font-family", "Impact")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
      return fill(i);
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.text;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the array you want using something like:

```
var countryList = document.querySelectorAll('.country');   
var countryNames = Array.prototype.map.call(countryList, function(c){return c.textContent});
```

Comment: Bear in mind that [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t11) is *less-supported* (thanks, IE 8) than [`document.querySelectorAll()`](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t14).

Comment: @DavidThomas That'd mean using ``document.querySelectorAll("*.country")`` instead right?

Comment: Or just `document.querySelectorAll('.country')`, or `document.querySelectorAll('div.country')`, but basically: yes, it uses CSS selector syntax.

Comment: Great, works! (Thanks for the tip regarding document.getElementByClassName as well).